# Trying to Understand Shortcodes.

Tags: plugins, shortcode

am completely stumped on this for some reason.

I have block of code that I had in my header.php

```
<?php 
if ( is_page("Home") ) {
if( have_rows('slider') ):  ?>
    <div class="my-slider"><ul >
<?php 
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('slider') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
       $image=get_sub_field('image');
       $title= get_sub_field('title');
       $byline= get_sub_field('byline');
      $link=  get_sub_field('link');


    ?>
    <li>
    <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>); min-height: 600px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover">

        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        </h3><?php echo $byline; ?><h3>
        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"></a>

    </li>


<?php endwhile ?>
</div>
<?php 
else :
    // no rows found ?> 
    <?php 
endif;
} else {
    // This is not the blog posts index

}
?>
<div>
```

It works just how I need it to. However, I am I need to be able to call that into specific locations and was thinking I could just turn this into a shortcode? or would plugin be better? Not sure how to begin and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using a shortcode, because its easy to use and at the same time efficient.
Below I have attached the code, how you can put your code into a shortcode.
the add_shortcode function is what you use when you want to create a shortcode.

To use it, you simply need to write [render_slider_shortcode] anywhere you want your slider to be displayed.

PS: There might be some error in the code which you gave. I coudnt test it on my site. But rest is fine. If you come accross any errors, make sure your code is getting proper values.

```
    // display a sub field value
add_shortcode('render_slider_shortcode', 'renderSLider');
function renderSLider()
{
  if ( is_page("Home") ) {
    if( have_rows('slider') ):  ?>
      <div class="my-slider"><ul >
      <?php
    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('slider') ) : the_row();

  $image=get_sub_field('image');
   $title= get_sub_field('title');
   $byline= get_sub_field('byline');
  $link=  get_sub_field('link');


  ?>
  <li>
  <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>); min-height: 600px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover">

    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    </h3><?php echo $byline; ?><h3>
    <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"></a>

  </li>


   <?php endwhile ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    else :
    // no rows found ?> 
       <?php 
      endif;
      }   else {
    // This is not the blog posts index

    }
  ?>
  </li>
 </div>
  <?php

}
```

Comment: Why you use `echo`?

Comment: the code works, had used advanced custom fields. DOes this then need to go in the Functions or can it be say in the header? but at any rate it is not pulling up

Comment: Even we don't recommend using echo in shortcode. But the stated sample code was using it and we din't touch it.

Comment: @user5288 You need add the code to the functions.php of your child theme. And you need to write <?php echo do_shortcode('renderSLider');?> at the same place where you wrote the above code.